# XML data display if only from certain category

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, cordova

I want my Phonegap iPhone app read a XML document I have on my server which contacts product listings, and display them but only when it a product is in a certain category.

At the moment this fully works but displays ALL products:

XML example:

```
    <item>
    <id>25579</id>
    <image><![CDATA[http://urlexample.com.au/wp-content/uploads/catablog/thumbnails/Speaker.jpg]]></image>
    <subimages>
    </subimages>
    <title><![CDATA[Product Name]]></title>
    <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
    <date>2014-02-04</date>
    <order>5</order>
    <link><![CDATA[http://www.productlink.com.au]]></link>
    <price><![CDATA[0]]></price>
    <product_code><![CDATA[]]></product_code>
    <categories>
        <category><![CDATA[Speaker]]></category>
        <category><![CDATA[Wireless]]></category>
    </categories>
</item>
```

Here is my code which WORKS:

```
     $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "http://www.test.com.au/accessories.xml",
           dataType: "xml",
            beforeSend : function() {$.mobile.loading('show')},
            complete    : function() {$.mobile.loading('hide')},
           success: parseXml
           });
           function parseXml(xml) {


                // alert(xml);
                $(xml).find('item').each(function(){

                    $("#datadock").append('<img src="' + $(this).find("image").text() + '" style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px;-moz-border-radius: 5px;border-radius: 5px;float:left;margin:1px;height:auto" width="49%">');

                });
```

Some products have different categories.

How can I only have it display products where "Category = "Speaker" for example. nothing some items have multiple category under 'categories'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
category = 'Speaker';
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    beforeSend: function () {},
    complete: function () {},
    success: parseXml
});

function parseXml(xml) {



    $(xml).find("item").each(function () {

        if ($(this).find('category').text().indexOf(category) != -1) {

            $("#datadock").append('<img src="' + $(this).find("image").text() + '" style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px;-moz-border-radius: 5px;border-radius: 5px;float:left;margin:1px;height:auto" width="49%">');

        }


    });
}
```